# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CENTOS

Tags: java, jdbc

I know this is very old thread but still I am not able to figure out on centos as I am new developer in java .

So Here is my question :

I am running one java class having jdbc code on centos from command line .

But while executing I am getting the below  error .

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JDBCExample
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JDBCExample
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Understood from the error that it requires mysql connector hence I installed that by following command .

```
yum install mysql-connector-java
```

but still getting the same I also tried downloading separately mysql-connector jar  file and run like .

```
java -classpath mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar JDBCExample
```

But this also returns the same error .Please tell me what might I am doing wrong .

Comment: The problem is not the jdbc driver, it is your class which is not being found.

Comment: Whats the fully qualified name for the class JDBCExample? Are you running the java command from the classpath directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting current directory in class path:

```
java -classpath .:mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar JDBCExample
```

Comment: java  -classpath  .;mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar JDBCExample
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

Comment: I mistakenly used the windows style .. try now with `:` as updated in answer

Comment: Glad it helped you, have fun coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the "mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar" with proper location or you can keep the mysql jar file in the same directory where **JDBCExample.class is there**.

Comment: both are present in root diirectory

Answer (score 0):

May be you have not added '.;' in the classpath - means to load class files from current directory as well ..

Comment: can you pl elaborate  i din't get .; where  to add